# Href shows different value in browser and it shows `javascript:` in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am currently working on python where I am supposed to extract all href value data using selenium in python.

When I access the website and check in through developer's tool it shows a proper href  value, but when I do it with selenium using `element.get_attribute('href')` it prints `javascript:`

Is there a solution to this so I can get the href  value rather than 'javascript:'

[image: This is how it is displayed in browser **(name blacked out for security reasons)**]

Code trials:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('website Name')
a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tupData')
print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

And all it prints is: **javascript:**

Is there a solution so that I can get  the href value rather than javascript: ??

Comment: is the class name 'tupData'  correct? i see a different class name in the screenshot.  What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: @Sureshmani yep its correct... tupData is the parent of "username name".. I tried with the anchor tag class name as well... the output I am getting is "href = javascript: " thats it

Comment: Is there multiple matches with class name - 'tupData'. I see you have used - find_elements. If this is true, then 'a' may contain more than 1 elements. you will have to loop through to get the href attribute.

Comment: You have to get the href attribute off of the A tag. From what you are stating (and what your code shows), you aren't getting it from the A tag. Post some of the surrounding HTML (as text, not as an image) and we can probably help you better. It sounds like you just need to fix your locator to get the A tag and it will work... the question is what is the locator that you will need.

Answer (score 0):

try to find the anchor element which contains the href attribute, rather than the parent element

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='tupData']//a")

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reach till the `<a>` tag to retrieve the `href` attribute inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.userName.name[href*='rexdex']"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='userName name' and contains(@href,'rexdex')]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried using  the xpath method.. It waited for 20 seconds and then gave me an error "<class 'NameError'>, NameError("name 'href' is not defined"), <traceback object at 0x000001D4BA6F7B48>"

Comment: Can you please update the question with the full error stack trace?